# Looking for help to make a decision about an offer from a company that seems a bit fishy

Tags: job-offer, recruitment, glassdoor

Recently, I got an offer from a company, I managed to pass all the interviews. 
It was not that hard nor too easy.

I also checked glassdoor and the reviews about the company are pretty bad... there are also fake reviews obviously made by the company itself to increase the overall rating... which sounds really fishy

My feelings are really kinda in between two extremes:

On one hand, pros:

- The package is okay (and I could negotiate more) this echoes what I found on glassdoor
- The technology is what I would like to work with (C# ASP.NET + JS) since I'm coming from a desktop app background and wanted to go to web development, this is an opportunity for me to finally make the move

On the other hand, cons:

- The recruitment process has been kind of messy, started with one position and ended up with another. The HR seems to not care that much until she got the technical feedback and now is of course pushing to get my signature on the contract asap, I understand at that point, but it gives me a feeling of inconsistency.
- The CTO puts a lot of emphasis about the team-leads because they graduated from a certain top notch college, "they are super smart" and over-bragging a lot. Also I would have to work hell a lot (which is also contradictory with the team-leader speech) but echoed what has been said on glassdoor aka OT OT OT. The thing is that I've been working 80 hours a week (and sometimes more) for 4 years, I'm literally wasted and I'm not lazy but I think 50 - 60 hours are okay. I don't want to burn out again, this is just not healthy, full stop.
- When I checked Linkedin, everybody who did not go to this so-called super top notch college did not last that long in the company (most of the executives come from the same education, seems like a glass-sealing, but apparently the policy is changing for about a year or two), anyway my point is that there is a turnover
- Some technical decisions are not really sound (even though I considered some excuses for that) especially when I asked about those reasons, the answers do not make that much to me.

Among the cons listed on glassdoor:

- Bad / toxic management
- Bad practices at software development, I have the feeling
- Pseudo-elite corporate culture and the vast majority comes from one of the top notch university (actually THE top notch one, ranked 1st). They have the reputation to be arrogant, still this is just a reputation and like for everybody there are nice and bad people everywhere. I agree that the exam to go this school is not that easy, but it relies hell a lot on maths (actually maths in my motherland is a sort of religion, unlike other countries, you're good at maths so then you can climb up the social ladder, otherwise not really, unless you go for politics [again studying at certain school only]). Anyway I was not bad at maths during my studies either, but it gives me feeling I am already discriminated.
- High turnover (which is contradictory with what the team-leader told me...)

Basically, yes this is  technically-speaking what I would like to do (apparently), but I just do not trust them, I don't feel like I can actually be part of the team. But still I managed to pass everything.

I mean if it is to learn everything by myself, again, I can do that at home (yes without the fat paycheck). I already have the motivation for that plus if I have to suffer from stupid discrimination because I have not been to the same university, it would be a pity.

One of my alumni told me once: "The team and your manager are equally important to the technologies you are willing to work with, if you cannot blend in or get along with your workcolleagues, you're gonna end up sad and frustrated at work and this definitely not gonna worth it."

I am struggling to go with them. It's like I have something no too bad but no that good either but maybe I should look for something else even if the package is not as good as this offer.

[EDIT]
Link removed

Comment: While I can feel your pain, you didn't really ask a question and we cannot help you with personal decisions. That's something you have to do yourself, life is risky, it's up to you which risk you take. If you actually have a question for this site, feel free to edit your post to make it more clear.

Comment: You posted your real name and list of cons about a company.  Does not compile.

Comment: I would think if anyone from that company sees this post, the offer may well be withdrawn.

Comment: Reading your post, you clearly do not want to work for them and have already made up your mind on that. Going into a job expressing serious concerns over whether you can trust your new boss is not a good way to start... Plus, with this post now online it's a matter of time before someone working there sees it or a cached version of it.

Answer (score 7):

**First** piece of advice: ***immediately remove the link*** to the company from your post - this can easily come back to haunt you later.

**Second**, I wouldn't use my real name, and picture when asking these sort of questions. For crying out loud, man!

**Third**, this place sounds like a pretty toxic/elitist work environment. Honestly, if I were treated like that by a company's HR department, or found *half* that many red flags regarding a potential employer I wouldn't even bother with the interviews - I'd simply cancel everything and move on.

That being said, I don't know your personal circumstances, so you have to make your own decision.